# Android LinearLayout not stretching full screen

Tags: android, layout, screen

Hi I'm writing an app for DroidX which is 480x854. I set up my AVD as follows:

target:API level 7
skin:480x854
hw.lcd.density:160

That's it. The emulator loads fine and looks great but my app doesn't fill_parent for some reason. See here:

[image]

It doesn't scale all the way up and I'm not sure why. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo_recruiting"
    android:background="#FF000000" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="30dip" />

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:text="@string/events"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/events_button"
        android:onClick="launchEventsMap"
        android:id="@+id/events_button"
        />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:text="@string/jobs"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/jobs_button"
        android:id="@+id/jobs_button"
        />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" 
        android:text="@string/applicants"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/applicants_button"
        android:id="@+id/applicants_button"
        />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" 
        android:text="@string/resumes"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/resumes_button"
        android:id="@+id/resumes_button"
        />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" 
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_button"
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would imagine layout_width="fill_parent" and layout_height="fill_parent" should do it....

Answer (score 5):

this screen resolution would fall into a septate screen size. Enable Large or AnyDensity under supported screens in the manifest. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your `ImageView` is outside of the `LinearLayout`, maybe try to wrap the whole thing in a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: No, its ImageView in inside the previous LinearLayout.